# Solve error Android Studio: Installation Failed with message null

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, null, installation

I'm getting the next error, I have tried: deleting the app, cleaning the project, also allowing the 'Unknown sources' in the phone settings but i get the same error with all the apps, even the new apps that i try to install just to test.

[image]
Also in the Console i get this error:

```
11/27 17:19:48: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\ozkr2805\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/ink.test
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/ink.test"
Error while accessing provider:com.rscja.secapp.provider.authcode
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find provider: com.rscja.secapp.provider.authcode
    at com.android.commands.pm.Pm$Command.execute(Pm.java:173)
    at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.main(Pm.java:252)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:276)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/ink.test
Success


Error while Installing APK
```

---

The device i have is: Chainway C71 Handheld Computer, don't know if this helps.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same problem. I have re-installed android studio and done a factory reset on the device, but it still fails. After flashing my smartphone the problem is fixed.

Comment: please add more explanation

Comment: Flashing in the world of mobile is like a re-install on a computer or laptop. In the smartphone there is Hardware, and of course hardware that can work if equipped with software.

Well, the process of re-instal smartphone software is called the process of flashing.

Comment: Finally, I solved the problem by doing the same with the help of the brand support, I reinstalled an updated software version with some tools that they gave me, thanks for the advice.